# How to create number of timer.scheduler inside the run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create 10 Timer.scheduler inside the run method, so i used for loop but its executing only once. not repeatedly calling the scheduler in this loop.

Please check my code below,

```
public void run()
    {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
       timer.schedule(task, 10000);
     }
    }
```

In this code I created 10 schedulers using for for loop but it executing only once. And how to differentiate each Scheduler

Please help me,

Comment: Can you turn this into a [full program that somebody could run](http://sscce.org/)? We have no idea what class a `timer` is, for example...

Comment: I'm removing Swing tag, because util.Timer isn't proper sheduler for Swing, btw question in this form isn't answerable here, should be closed and down_voted (as you can see)

Comment: @user: dcsohl is right, It would always help you more if you also provide the Error trace. Rather you will be able to resolve problem by yourself once you see details in error trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using java.util.Timer then possibly the reason why it's only running the task once is because a java.util.TimerTask can only be scheduled once.  This code will run the first scheduled task but will fail with an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled` there after.

To differentiate each scheduled task you could do something like this.  Each scheduled NamedTimerTask will have its own name.  You can choose to modify this to add whatever you need to identify your scheduled tasks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        timer.schedule(new NamedTimerTask("task" + i) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

static abstract class NamedTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    final String name;

    NamedTimerTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```